# Numpy/Python numerical instability issue multiplying large arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have created a function to rotate a vector by a quaternion:

```
def QVrotate_toLocal(Quaternion,Vector):

    #NumSamples x Quaternion[w,x,y,z]
    #NumSamples x Vector[x,y,z]
    #For example shape (20000000,4) with range 0,1
    #            shape (20000000,3) with range -100,100
    #All numbers are float 64s 

    Quaternion[:,2]*=-1
    x,y,z=QuatVectorRotate(Quaternion,Vector)
    norm=np.linalg.norm(Quaternion,axis=1)
    x*=(1/norm)
    y*=(1/norm)
    z*=(1/norm)
    return np.stack([x,y,z],axis=1)
```

Everything within QuatVectorRotate is addition and multiplication of (20000000,1) numpy arrays

For the data I have (20million samples for both the quaternion and vector), every time I run the code the solution oscillates between a (known) correct solution and very incorrect solution. Never deviating from pattern correct,incorrect,correct,incorrect...

This kind of numerical oscillation in static code usually means there is an ill-conditioned matrix which is being operated on, python is running out of floating point precision, or there is a silent memory overflow somewhere.

There is little linear algebra in my code, and I have checked and found the norm line to be static with every run. The problem seems to be happening somewhere in lines a= ... to  d= ...

Which led me to believe that given these large arrays I was running out of memory somewhere along the line. This could still be the issue, but I dont believe it is; I have 16gb memory, and while running I never get above 75% usage. But again, I do not know enough about memory allocation to definitively rule this out. I attempted to force garbage collection at the beginning and end of the function to no avail.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I just reproduced this issue with the following data and same behavior was observed.

```
Q=np.random.random((20000000,4))
V=np.random.random((20000000,3))
```

Comment: Edited out some math to make things more readable and highlight the issue in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `Quaternion[:,2]*=-1` in the first line, you are mutating the `Quaternion` array. This is not a local copy of that array, but the actual array you pass in from the outside.

So every time you run this code, you have different signs on those elements. After having run the function twice, the array is back to the start (since, obviously, `-1*-1 = 1`).

One way to get around this is to make a local copy first:

```
Quaternion_temp = Quaternion.copy()
```

Comment: Oh wow... that completely eluded me. Could you elaborate on why Quaternion*=-1 is not a stored as a local copy but mutates the array that I pass from the outside while a,b,c,d are actually local variables?

Comment: @IanCampbellMoore 1. Because `*=` is in-place multiplication and 2. because if the way Python passes variables, you can actually mutate a mutable object from within a function. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/4042267) for more info on the latter.